# OpenSSL and ETSI QKD protocol

Tags: openssl, ssh, quantum-key-distribution

Has anyone integrated OpenSSL with the ETSI QKD key request protocol? I want to make my most critical SSH sessions quantum-safe by integrating with a QKD system and it appears the QKD vendors use the following API specification for the two side (Alice and Bob) to request keys: https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/QKD/001_099/014/01.01.01_60/gs_qkd014v010101p.pdf

I don't see anything publicly available but was thinking maybe someone here has played with this.

Comment: I'm impressed by the level of formalism of this standardization effort, but not the slightest by the usefulness of the whole endeavor. Who wants to communicate thru a series of intermediary trusted nodes, that [each must be assumed secure](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/QKD/001_099/014/01.01.01_60/gs_qkd014v010101p.pdf#page=9)? Independently, what makes today's claims of security of individual KQD links more credible than yesterday's claims on that tune, [experimentally refuted](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4593) by rather simple means?

Comment: For some threats to the security of QKD known by 2018, read [this](https://www.etsi.org/images/files/ETSIWhitePapers/etsi_wp27_qkd_imp_sec_FINAL.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A28%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C61%2C728%2C0%5D).

Comment: BTW: if you are that paranoid, why aren't you working off the Open Quantum Safe branch (so you could get both QKD *and* postquantum crypto...)

Comment: I don't fully trust QKD or post-quantum crypto (PQC), especially since the Rainbow DSA was just this year torched using a laptop. But the idea is that it's important to be able to integrate with both of these technologies. The ETSI standard seems to be the best way to integrate with the broadest suite of QKD products, so that's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Not 014, but 014 in a hackathon: https://brunorijsman.github.io/openssl-qkd/doc/implementing-qkd-in-openssl.html